Why can't I see the modifications I added to the code when I run the code I cloned from GitHub in Android Studio?
I believe I have an example already saved in my Android Studio project that runs  whenever I click the run button. However, as I've been working on the project, I've encountered some challenges. Despite making modifications and removing certain components, I haven't noticed any significant changes when I run the app. It's been quite frustrating not being able to see the expected results. Additionally, I've been struggling to grasp the overall structure of the project. In particular, there's a folder named "com.example.runalyze (test)" that I'm not entirely sure about. I'm wondering if this folder has any connection to the issues I'm facing or if it's just an unrelated part of the project.

How are you building and deploying the app?  You are building it, and not just assuming changes will automatically go to the phone, right?  Also the (test) folder is your unit tests.
